# Bash f// notation?

Tags: bash

Trying to figure out exactly what this script is doing in this part.

```
for f in $FILES
do
    ORIGINAL_FILE=${f//$FILE_PATH/}
```

This is later used in a diff statement:

```
DIFFER=`diff $f $REPOS_PATH/$ORIGINAL_FILE`
```

What exactly is the double slash (//)? Is that 'f' the variable above or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`${…}` is [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion). There are many variants of parameter expansion, determined by the punctuation after the variable name. `${f//$FILE_PATH/}` is the value of `f` with every substring matching the pattern `$FILE_PATH` (i.e. the pattern is the value of the variable `FILE_PATH`) replaced by an empty string.

Given what comes afterwards in the script, it's poorly written: clearly `$FILE_PATH` is expected to be at the beginning of the value of `f`, and the replacement should be

```
ORIGINAL_FILE=${f#"$FILE_PATH"}
```

Also that script is missing some double quotes, so [it will break with paths containing spaces and other special characters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters).

Comment: Nope, this would be `${f/$FILE_PATH/}`

Comment: @ddbug No, `${f/$FILE_PATH/}` would replace the first match. With two slashes after the variable names, all the occurrences are replaced.

Comment: The script isn't missing double quotes, so much as it is fragilely relying on  `$FILES` to expand to a space-separated list of file names.